# What stats should King Wolf have?

Tags: combat, npc, 7th-sea

Some PC's in my game may possibly be going to pick a Fight with King Wolf of Ussuran legend (from *Nations of Theah #7: Ussura*).  While not expressly impossible for them to win, I have about 4 different versions of what his stats should be.  If you were going to make combat stats for King Wolf using the Roll and Keep system what would they be?

Comment: As per my answer below, it would help to know what are you after. How strong your wolves are? What do you dislike about official rules indicator? Your wolf king is to be how strong / cunning / dangerous?

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on what you want to achieve**.

Ussuran rule-book says to start with animal stats - I see no problem with that. It's a wolf, after all. They offer some modifiers, but not to attack/damage rolls. Up to you if you want to honour this or not. However thinking combat...

- first of all are your heroes dumb enough to kill/hurt Matushka's nobility in Ussura? Don't they know what this means? How will they HIDE from scores of enraged beasts in their territory? Are they so great at hiding, tracking, etc. that they believe bears, wolverines and wolves shan't match their skills? these are animals, yes, but intelligent, able to reason and remember. Their scent shall be reviled and blood hunts shall start.
- second - it's a KING. if he's heroic, there will be other wolves who will jump to battle to protect him - he may even have a honour guard just as human king would. And if he's a villain, will he fight? Why not offer them a poisoned meal first and finish them later? Or why not say to his vassals, that they offended him, so vassals would do the dirty job?
- third - WOLF is key. Wolfs are pack animals, they don't hunt alone (usually, that is). Wolf packs are entirely different matter, and it would be no surprise to add them something while they fight together.
- while we're on packs, wolf pack often is wolf's kin - how many sons has  your wolf king sired? do they want to inherit or are they loyal (more likely, but it's your Ussura)

All in all - that's most likely the the mightiest wolf in all of Ussura, and one of most mighty beasts there are (four kings in Ussura would usually be "top dogs" of all normal beasts). So, if your average wolf there has 3 brawns, he's likely to have more. I don't think anyone here can offer you stats per se, that's relative to how you played so far.

Of course, if you want, it may be a very wise wolf... but past his prime. Not much of a physical threat (say, will be tired quickly, so if heroes can last two rounds, it's their win), but wise and cunning.

### Summarizing

1. Decide what you want. Tough enemy? Battle that earns respect, then friendship?
2. Villain or Hero?
3. Why would it fight and what it has at his disposal when he meets your team?
4. How much other wolves will allow to happen to him? Will they jump in? When?
5. Then think stats.
6. If he's king... there shall be repercussions for hurting him, good or bad, unless it's "let's spar, hero, so I can judge if you're worthy".

My take on it. :-)